# A holomorphic function in the unit disc without radial limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I try to do some problems from Rudin's RCA Chapter 13 (Approximation by Rational Functions). It’s Exercise 5: For $n=1,2,3,\ldots$, let $\Delta_n$ be a closed disc in $U$, and let $L_n$ be an arc (a homeomorphic image of $[0,1]$) in $U \setminus \Delta_n$ which intersects every radius of $U$. There are polynomials $P_n$ which are very small on $\Delta_n$ and **more or less arbitrary on $L_n$**. Show that $\{\Delta_n\}$, $\{L_n\}$, and $\{P_n\}$ can be so chosen that the series $f=\Sigma P_n$ defined a function $f \in H(U)$ which has no radial limit at any point of $T$.

I can apply Runge's Theorem to construct polynomials $P_n$ which are very small on $\Delta_n$. However, I don't understand what the phrase "**more or less arbitrary on $L_n$**" means. It is very unclear to me, so I can't solve this problem. Does anyone know what this phrase means and how to prove this exercise?

Comment: [Related answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/248368/8157)

Answer (score 1):

"more or less arbitrary" means that they can approximate any analytic function in the neighborhood of $L_n$ as well as one wants while also approximating well a given analytic function in a disc away from said neighborhood - polynomials are finite maps of the plane in the sense that the preimage of any point is finite, so obviously the 
"more or less" is needed

To finish the problem, one can take $\Delta_n$ the disc of radius $1-\frac{1}{4n}$, $L_n$ an arc that goes say three quarters around on the circle of radius $1-\frac{1}{4n+1}$ them moves there to the radius $1-\frac{1}{4n+2}$ and keeps going another half around the circle, so overall it goes around and a quarter say but still is an arc with different ends and take then $V_n$ a small tubular neighborhood of $L_n$ disjoint of $\Delta_n$ (eg you can take the width $\frac{1}{(4n+2)^3})$.

Construct inductively $P_n, n \ge 1$ as follows.

Take $P_0=0$ and then $f_1(z)=P_0(z), z \in \Delta_1, f_1(z)=1, z \in V_1$, is analytic on the union of those two open sets as they are disjoint,  and since the complement of $\Delta_1 \cup V_1$ is obviously connected, we can construct a polynomial $P_1$ s.t. $|P_1(z)-f_1(z)| \le \frac{1}{2}, z \in \Delta_1 \cup V_1$.

Assume now $P_n$ constructed and then $f_{n+1}(z)=P_n(z), z \in \Delta_{n+1}, f_{n+1}(z)=1, z \in V_{n+1}, n$ even, $f_{n+1}(z)=0, z \in V_{n+1}, n$ odd is analytic on the union of those two open sets as they are disjoint,  and since the complement of $\Delta_{n+1} \cup V_{n+1}$ is obviously connected, we can construct a polynomial $P_{n+1}$ s.t. $|P_{n+1}(z)-f_{n+1}(z)| \le \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}, z \in \Delta_{n+1} \cup V_{n+1}$ (technically Runge applies on compact subsets of this, but we can just enlarge it a little, while clearly we respect the construction for $P_0, P_1$ etc)

Pick $K$ a compact disc in $U$ (open unit disc), then $K \subset \Delta_n, n \ge n_K$, hence $|P_{n+1}(z)-P_n(z)| \le \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}, z \in K, n \ge n_K$, hence there is a function $f$ on $K$ s.t $P_n \to f$ uniformly on $K$ and $f$ is analytic in the interior of $K$, hence by taking these compact discs to fill $U$, we get $f$ analytic on $U$, s.t $P_n \to f$ uniformly on compact sets.

But now let $z \in V_{2n}$. Since $V_{2n} \subset \Delta_m, m \ge 2n+1$, we get $|f(z)| \le (\sum_{k=2n}^{\infty}{|P_{k+1}(z)-P_k(z)|})+|P_{2n}(z)| \le (\sum_{k=2n}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{k+1}})+ \frac{1}{2^{2n}} = \frac{1}{2^{2n-1}}$, while if $z \in V_{2n+1}$, we get $|f(z)-1| \le \frac{1}{2^{2n}}$ since $|P_{2n}| \le \frac{1}{2^{2n}}$ on $V_{2n}$, but $|P_{2n+1}-1| \le \frac{1}{2^{2n+1}}$ on $V_{2n+1}$, Since by construction any radius intersects all sets $V_n$, $f$ cannot have a radial limit anywhere!

Note that any such function must be highly unbounded in the sense that for almost all the points on the boundary the image of any triangular neighborhood of it (as small as you want) is dense in the plane.